# RAID mode on XPS 9550

Tags: system-installation, dell, 17.04, raid, mdadm

Recently I got a Dell XPS 9550 and have gotten Ubuntu to run on on it when I put the ssd in AHCI mode. However, I was wondering if it is possible to get ubuntu to detect the ssd when in raid mode which uses Intel RST I believe. By default using the installer bundled with ubuntu it can not detect the ssd using the raid utility built into the installer. Apparently, Intel RST is compatible with linux through mdadm, but I have yet to figure out how to get this to work. I was curious if anyone know how to use mdadm to be able to install ubuntu in raid mode and if not are there any real advantages of Raid mode over AHCI? Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Intel White Paper are not mentioning about Ubuntu as officially supported for MD Raid ([Sources](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/rst-linux-paper.pdf), go to page 5). They speak only about Redhat and Suse.

Anyway, MD Raid is also named as Fake Raid or Software Raid. I recommand do not use Intel MD Raid and only use Raid Software provided by Ubuntu (Available with NetInstall).

Comment: The raid utility provided with ubuntu is unable to recognize the ssd, but according to what I have read so far the xps 9550 does use intel rst. I am not sure if the raid utility provided with ubuntu does not support intel rst or not.

Comment: What I suggested is putting your hard drive in AHCI as there is no real advantage to use Raid mode as it still a Raid software. The only benefits of Raid mode could be to rebuild your broken hard drive directly from BIOS, but does't provide any improved performance.